# using lambda.min to extrace coefficients from model trained with glmnet

Tags: r, glmnet

I am using `glmnet` to train the logistic regression model and then try to obtain the coefficients with the specific `lambda`. I used the simple example here:

```
load("BinomialExample.RData")

fit = glmnet(x, y, family = "binomial")
coef(fit, s = c(0.05,0.01))
```

I have checked the values of `fit$lambda`, however, I could not find the specific values of 0.05 or 0.01 in `fit$lambda`. So how could `coef` return the coefficients with a `lambda` not in the `fit$lambda` vector.

Comment: Questions about *programming, debugging, or performing routine operations within a statistical computing platform* are [off-topic](http://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) here.

Comment: You can't.  If you really need to do so, consider linearly interpolating between the next largest and next smallest values of lambda.

Answer (score 0):

This is explained in the help for `coef.glmnet`, specifically the `exact` argument:

> **`exact`**
>
> This argument is relevant only when predictions are made at values of s (lambda) different from those used in the fitting of the original model. If `exact=FALSE` (default), then the predict function uses linear interpolation to make predictions for values of s (lambda) that do not coincide with those used in the fitting algorithm. While this is often a good approximation, it can sometimes be a bit coarse. With `exact=TRUE`, these different values of s are merged (and sorted) with `object$lambda`, and the model is refit before predictions are made.